# erb idiom to handle undefined variable

Tags: ruby, erb

I'm trying to write some puppet .erb, I'd like to handle this "environment" variable if it's:

- undefined
- a string with newlines
- an array.

I've got as far as this:

```
<% Array(environment).join("\n").split(%r{\n}).each do |f| %>
one line: <%= f %>
<% end %>
```

But haven't gotten around the undefined case yet.  I've tried this

```
<% if (defined?(environment)).nil? %?
<% Array(environment).join("\n").split(%r{\n}).each do |f| %>
one line: <%= f %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

but am still getting "(erb):11: undefined local variable or method `environment' for main:Object (NameError)" when trying to test it like this:

```
ruby -rerb -e "environmentUNDEFINEME= [ 'cronvar=cronval', 'var2=val2' ]; 
puts ERB.new(File.read('templates/job.erb')).result"
```

Sorry this is so basic, but somebody's got to ask the easy questions.  Any help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this:

```
<% if defined?(environment) %>
  <% Array(environment).each do |f| %>
  one line: <%= f %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I didn't understand why you joining on new lines and then splitting on them again, so I removed it from the example.

Comment: That makes no sense.  If environment is defined, the entire block is skipped.

Comment: I was splitting on newlines and rejoining so that I could accept both

environment => "foo=bar\nbaz=bam"

and 

environment => ["foo=bar", "baz=bam" ]

Comment: <% if defined?(environment) %> works.  Oh, hah, I think I was misunderstanding the ".nil?" in my original code.  My question was even dumber than I thought. My fail. :-)